# Can I replace the power operator (**) using recursion?

Tags: python, function, recursion

Applying the principle of Recursion during function definition  makes coding less difficult and more interesting.

For example I have this simple function to find the power of a particular number:

```
def power(a, b):
   return a**b
```

But what if I decide not to use  `**`, in this case, I want to apply the principle of Recursion.

I want to call the same function within the block scope. 
I tried this :

```
def power (a, b) :
   return a*power(a, b-1)
```

Output an error message on printing

```
print power(3,3) 

Runtime Error: maximum recursion depth  exceeded
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I improve my code?

Comment: you forgot a STOP condition. also, what if b is negative?

Comment: Thanks for response. In what part must I include a stopping condition

Comment: @Udonse: when should you *stop* calculating the power? Right now you are trying to calculate `3 * power(3, 2)` is `3 * 3 * power(3, 1)` is `3 * 3 * 3 * power(3, 0)` is `3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * power(3, -1)` is ... and so on into infinity as you never reach a base condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A codified example of the comments:

```
def power(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    return a * power(a, b - 1)
```

Recursion requires a *base case* — something which tells the program "Hey, this is as far down as you should go. Start returning things!"

Edit: For what it's worth, recursion is not guaranteed to be implemented well in Python. The language specification makes no assertions about how to handle recursion, which means a deep recursion will overflow the stack. (This is in contrast to other languages, such as most functional programming languages, where recursion is more optimized.) On my computer, with CPython:

```
>>> def power(a, b):
...     if b == 0:
...         return 1
...     return a * power(a, b - 1)
>>>
>>> power(1, 10)
1
>>> power(1, 981)
1
>>> power(1, 982)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    power(1, 982)
  File "<input>", line 4, in power
    return a * power(a, b - 1)
  File "<input>", line 4, in power
    return a * power(a, b - 1)
  File "<input>", line 4, in power
    return a * power(a, b - 1)
  [Previous line repeated 978 more times]
  File "<input>", line 2, in power
    if b == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Additionally, your CPU might be able to do exponentiation more efficiently than regular multiplication, so it might be slower to write this function recursively than with the built-in operator.

Comment: Wow thanks.. Which implies that I must indicate a stopping condition

Comment: @Udonse yes, all recursion requires base cases, or else the recursion would never stop!

Comment: @Udonse glad to help! If you don't mind, though, clicking the checkmark next to my answer to "accept" it would be much appreciated. I'm all about those useless internet points. :)

Comment: @ Pierce.. I have less than 15 reputation.. It's not responding  upon clicking

Comment: I have done that now.. Am so grateful for your response

Comment: @Udonse much appreciated. Thank you! Good luck with your learning! :)

Comment: `return a * power(a, b - 1)` is not a tail call, so tail call optimization is not ordinarily possible without changing the code, or without some other optimization transforming the call into a tail call.

Comment: @DietrichEpp your point is definitely true; edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the "divide and conquer" strategy both for speed and to calculate very large powers without blowing out the stack.  Both the relationships and the implementation below assume non-negative integer values for the power argument.

You already noted that `a**b == a * a**(b-1)`.  However, it's also true that when `b` is even `a**b == (a*a)**(b/2)`, which cuts the problem size in half rather than reducing it by 1.  As always with recursion, you'll also need the base case `a**0 == 1`.  Putting it all together, we get:

```
def power(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    result = power(a * a, b // 2)           # calculate the halved problem
    return a * result if b & 1 else result  # and multiply by a if b is odd
```

which allows us to calculate `power(2, 2000)` as:

114813069527425452423283320117768198402231770208869520047764273682576626139237031385665948631650626991844596463898746277344711896086305533142593135616665318539129989145312280000688779148240044871428926990063486244781615463646388363947317026040466353970904996558162398808944629605623311649536164221970332681344168908984458505602379484807914058900934776500429002716706625830522008132236281291761267883317206598995396418127021779858404042159853183251540889433902091920554957783589672039160081957216630582755380425583726015528348786419432054508915275783882625175435528800822842770817965453762184851149029376.

The recursion stack growth is O(log b) with this algorithm—proportional to 11 for `b == 2000`.

Comment: With these I guess I can solve more complex problem. Thanks @pjs.. Need to study u codes

Comment: You're welcome.  I always try to find a halving approach with recursion, it's not always possible but makes a big difference when it is.